# Delay after hitting escape

Tags: linux, keyboard

I'm on a Linux system (arch). I've noticed there's a delay after hitting escape, before it registers. This happens inside of the terminal. But oddly, it does not happen inside of vim, even though vim is inside of the terminal.

I'm using zsh, although I assume that's not relevant to the issue.

What are ways to debug why there is a delay before ESC is registered?

Using xmodmap to swap capslock and escape doesn't solve the issue either, which makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

The delay is a feature. See [Eliminating delays on <kbd>ESC</kbd> in `vim` and `zsh`](https://www.johnhawthorn.com/2012/09/vi-escape-delays/).

> This delay exists because many keys (arrows keys, <kbd>ALT</kbd>) rely on it as an escape character.

For this reason each program that uses <kbd>ESC</kbd> and keys that rely on the escape character may implement a delay on its own.

> #### vim
>
> A simple solution for `vim` is to `:set esckeys`. However, this will break any sequences using escape in insert mode.
>
> Another solution is to use `timeoutlen` and `ttimeoutlen`. `timeoutlen` is used for mapping delays, and `ttimeoutlen` is used for key code delays. My `.vimrc` has:
>
> ```
> set timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=0
> ```
>
> It might be more reasonable to give `ttimeoutlen` a more reasonable value, like 10ms, although I have encountered no issues yet.
>
> […]
>
> #### zsh
>
> ZSH uses the `KEYTIMEOUT` parameter to determine how long to wait (in hundredths of a second) for additional characters in sequence. Default is 0.4 seconds.
>
> ```
> # 10ms for key sequences
> KEYTIMEOUT=1
> ```

---

I believe the situation is more complicated inside `tmux` or `screen` because each can add its own delay. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25638/108618) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/385844/108618) respectively.

Comment: `bash` seems to implement this delay as well.

Comment: @Dai Yes, configurable with `keyseq-timeout` variable in Readline, I think. Not a surprise, since any application that reads terminal input character-by-character [needs to deal with the same problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/608179/108618).